# How To Use Camera AV Foundatons

Tags: ios, avfoundation

My basic task is show what the user is looking at (camera) and let him take a picture of it. I do not want to use the Camera and Photo Library. I think that the library I should use is the AV Foundations library. I have looked at the sample code provide:

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html
```

However I do not understand how to implement this. What do I need to do to get pictures of what the user is looking at of a direct feed?

Comment: follow this [link](http://www.ios-developer.net/category/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/camera). It is good place to start.

Comment: Look for avfoundation programming guide > Media capture

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple tutorial about how to use AV Foundation overlay.

```
http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273
```

This tutorial talks about how to setup the live camera feed and overlay the feed with objects.